Marcinkiewiecz-Zygmund inequality Proof
I am reading Additive Combinatorics Notes by Thomas Bloom and get stucked on the proof of Marcinkiewiecz-Zygmund inequality proof (page 48-49). So we want to show that if $m\in \mathbb{N}, X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent complex-valued random variables with mean $0$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left| \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right|^{2m}\leq (4m)^m \mathbb{E}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^2 \right)^{m}.
$$
At one step, which is line 9 of page 49, he wrote that we want to bound $\mathbb{E}_{\varepsilon_i} |\sum_i \varepsilon_i x_i|^{2m}$ from above where $x_i=X_i-Y_i$ and then use expansion and triangle inequality to get $$
\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_n=2m}\binom{2m}{k_1,\dots,k_n}|x_1|^{k_1}\dots |x_n|^{k_n}|\mathbb{E}\varepsilon_1^{k_1}\dots \varepsilon_n^{k_n}|.
$$
My question is, why do we have the expectation inside the absolute value for $\varepsilon_1^{k_1}\dots \varepsilon_n^{k_n}$ instead of outside?

Please include your specific question to your problem statement rather than external links.

@Euclid ok, let me edit my question

Expand out the $2m$th power first, which gives you
$$ \mathbb{E} \sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=2m}\binom{2m}{k_1,\ldots,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n} \epsilon_1^{k_1}\cdots \epsilon_n^{k_n}.$$
Well, not quite, because there's a bunch of conjugation signs among some of the $x_i$. But now you can take the expectation inside so this is equal to
$$ \sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=2m}\binom{2m}{k_1,\ldots,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n} \mathbb{E} \epsilon_1^{k_1}\cdots \epsilon_n^{k_n}.$$
And now you can take absolute values inside by the triangle inequality (so the earlier ambiguity about conjugation signs is irrelevant, because we're taking absolute values of each $x_i$ anyway.
The reason I skipped this step in the written lecture notes is because I couldn't work out a nice way of actually writing out the proper expression with all the conjugation signs in the right places, and since they disappear immediately after creation it didn't seem like a problem worth solving. (In the actual lectures I explained it on the board.)

I see, thank you. My doubt is exactly what you wrote since I thought you imply just use absolute value everywhere, but that is not true. I agree putting conjugation signs is annoying to write on the notes.
